# jQuery refer to element of the if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter some elements based on it's data attributes. Here's the code I've written until now:

```
$(document).on('change', '.filter-mobile_categories :radio[name="filterSize"]', function(){
  const size_value = this.value;
  $('.li-product').hide();
  if ($('.li-product').dataset.sizes !== "" && $('.li-product').dataset.sizes.indexOf('-' + size_value + '-')){
    //refer to those elements
  }
});
```

How do I refer to the elements that comply with the if's condition?
Or using a totally different method like `.filter()` would be better? If so, how?
Thanks!

Comment: `$('.li-product')` returns a jQuery object which has no `dataset` property. Either use the DOM node or `.data()`

Comment: And don't query the DOM three times with the exact same selector. Store the result in a variable and use that.

Comment: I think you're almost there indeed. What I would do is first try to filter these items into a variable, the check for the length of this variable and loop over it if > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question suggesting `filter()` is indeed the better way to go here, as it provides you with a jQuery object containing only the relevant elements. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.filter-mobile_categories :radio[name="filterSize"]', function() {
  const size_value = this.value;
  let $products = $('.li-product').hide();
  let $filtered = $products.filter((i, el) => el.dataset.sizes !== '' && el.dataset.sizes.indexOf(`-${size_value}-`));
  
  // use $filtered here...
});
```